# SQL Server - Two columns in child table referencing same column in parent table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, ssms

As reported by the title I have a child table (`Contracts`) in which there are two columns, each of them referencing the same key column in the parent table (`Clients`).

The reason why I have made this design choice is that the parent table contains the clients but at the same time a client could be a provider company for another client.

The problem which I am encountering is that: the table are created correctly but the foreign keys (related only to these two tables) seems to be duplicated in both the child table (Contracts - the place where they should be stay) and in Clients (don't know why they are shown also here). I can see this duplicate when I open the SSMS relationship designer and I see in both tables the presence of the two foreign keys.

Here below the code which generate me this trouble (will be present other tables not mentioned here because them do not create issues):
Table Clients:

```
CREATE TABLE tblClients 
(
    VAT_Number NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Country_EID NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    User_EID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Is_Company_Group BIT NOT NULL,
    Recording_Date SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_tblClients_Recording_Date DEFAULT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, GETDATE()),
    General_Notes NVARCHAR(300),

    CONSTRAINT tblClients_Country_EID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (Country_EID) REFERENCES tblCountryLkp(Country_ID),

    CONSTRAINT tblClients_User_EID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (User_EID) REFERENCES tblUsers(User_ID)
);
```

Table Contracts:

```
CREATE TABLE tblContracts  
(
    Contract_ID_Old NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Contract_ID_New NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    EVAT_Client NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Billing_Type_EID INT NOT NULL,
    User_EID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Type_EID INT NOT NULL,
    EVAT_Company NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Status_EID INT NOT NULL,
    Recording_Date SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_tblContracts_Recording_Date DEFAULT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, GETDATE()),

    PRIMARY KEY (Contract_ID_Old, Contract_ID_New),

    CONSTRAINT tblContracts_Billing_Type_EID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (Billing_Type_EID) REFERENCES tblBillingTypeLkp(Billing_Type_ID),

    CONSTRAINT tblContracts_User_EID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (User_EID) REFERENCES tblUsers(User_ID),

    CONSTRAINT tblContracts_Type_EID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (Type_EID) REFERENCES tblContractTypeLkp(Contract_Type_ID),

    CONSTRAINT tblContracts_Status_EID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (Status_EID) REFERENCES tblStatusLkp(Status_ID),

    CONSTRAINT tblContracts_EVAT_Client_Company_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (EVAT_Client) REFERENCES tblClients(VAT_Number),

    CONSTRAINT tblContracts_EVAT_Company_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (EVAT_Company) REFERENCES tblClients(VAT_Number)
);
```

Could someone help me to find the issue and to avoid that the duplication of the foreign keys related to `EVAT_Client` and `EVAT_Company` fields are created?

Thank you.

Comment: can you paste the image anywhere ?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying here to the question of KumarHarsh (since in the comments I didn't get to post images).
In the image will be present the screenshot of the table tblContracts where it could be seen the two foreign keys which, correctly, are defined for this table.
And the screenshot of the table tblClients where it could be seen the two same foreign keys which, in my opinion, are present incorrectly for the table tblClients.

I hope this helps to find the issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Anyone has any idea of the issue? Please, help me....I don't find anything that explain me what is the issue..